# turbogear kid template for loop

Tags: python, turbogears2

i have inherited a project built in TurboGears that uses kid as the templating and wanted to find out what would be a better way to re-organize the following code:

```
<div py:if="style.style[0] == 'N' "> 
    <img src="${tg.config('cccorder.api_url')}/resources/logos/logoN.gif" alt="Clothing" />  </div>
<div py:if="style.style[0] == 'E' "> 
    <img src="${tg.config('cccorder.api_url')}/resources/logos/logoEP.gif" alt="Clothing" />  </div>
<div py:if="style.style[0] == 'S' ">
    <img src="${tg.config('cccorder.api_url')}/resources/logos/logoSA.gif" alt="Clothing" />
</div>
```

the only variables here are the 'N', 'E' and 'S' and the actual images that change depending on the `if`

any advise much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while since I've worked with TurboGears so I'm a little rusty.  One simple way to improve it would be to rename the files to logoN.gif, logoE.gif, logoS.gif, then you could consolidate the 7 lines into 3.  Alternatively, you could adjust the value of style.style[0] to be N, EP, SA.

```
<div>
    <img src="${tg.config('cccorder.api_url')}/resources/logos/logo${style.style[0]}.gif" alt="Clothing" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps!